# On cardinality of the two groups $\operatorname {Aut} \mathbb Q$ and $\operatorname {Aut} \mathbb R .$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ What is the cardinality of $\operatorname {Aut} \mathbb Q$ and $\operatorname {Aut} \mathbb R$  (where $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q$ are groups under usual addition) ???

$\mathbf {My \ approach} :$ Actually, I thought this problem during trying that if two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic, then $\operatorname {Aut} G_1$ and $\operatorname {Aut} G_2$ are too whether $G_1$ and $G_2$ are finitely generated or not .

Here, for each $n \in \mathbb N$ , define : $f_n : r \mapsto nr$ for each rational $r$ ; and $f_\alpha : x \mapsto \alpha x$ for each real $x$ ; then $f_n \in \operatorname {Aut} \mathbb Q$ and  $f_\alpha \in \operatorname {Aut} \mathbb R .$

Now, I can't approach further about finding other automorphisms, though there are at least $\mathbb R$- many permutations of $\mathbb Q$, all of them are obviously not automorphisms.

Comment: You should be able to prove that if $1\mapsto t$ then $\frac{m}{n}\mapsto \frac{m}{n}t$ which solves the problem for $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $Aut(\Bbb{R})$ is a bit tricky. If you assume the Axiom of Choice, then $\Bbb{R}$ has a basis as a vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$ (the basis has the cardinality of the continuum), and the automorphisms are just $\Bbb{Q}$-linear transformations (essentially for the reasons outlined in Severin's answer). If you don't accept Choice, then ... ask a set theorist. The cardinality of permutations of those basis elements exceeds that of the continuum (IIRC), so this may also affect the cardinality of $Aut(\Bbb{R})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There cannot be more automorphisms of $(\Bbb R,+)$ than there are permutatiosn of $\Bbb R$.
On the other hand,
$\Bbb R$ is a $|\Bbb R|$-dimensional $\Bbb Q$-vector space. If we split a basis into two disjoint subset $B_1,B_2$ of same cardinality, then any bijection $B_1\to B_2$ gives rise to an (involutory) automorphism of $(\Bbb R,+)$, and the number of such bijections is the same as the number of  permutations of $\Bbb R$. So the answer for $(\Bbb R,+)$ is 
$$|\Bbb R|^{|\Bbb R|}$$

Comment: I'm prepared to be wrong about this, but IIRC if we don't accept the axiom of choice, then this cardinality may be lower. I'm just parroting a recollection - can't explain it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That it is true—it is possible that the only homomorphisms are continuous ones and there are continuum many of those. I have a question on here, and MO, and that asks if it is possible to be strictly under the bound given in this answer but greater than continuum (so far no answers).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer (but too long to be a comment). I don't know about the cardinality of $Aut(\mathbb{R})$.

Note that if $\varphi$ is an automorphism of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$, then we have
$$ \varphi(1) = \varphi (\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \varphi(\frac{1}{n})= n \varphi(\frac{1}{n}) $$
Thus, we have
$$ \varphi(\frac{1}{n}) =\frac{\varphi(1)}{n}$$
Using a similar trick as before we get
$$ \varphi(\frac{m}{n}) = \frac{m}{n}  \varphi(1).$$
This means that all automorphisms of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ are of the form
$$ x \mapsto q x $$
for some $q\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: But Sir what about $\mathbb R ???$

Comment: Should have stressed that this is not a real answer. I don't know about $Aut(\mathbb{R})$.